# Deleting certain characters from a string

Tags: python, string

I try to figure out how I can delete certain characters from a string. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I would appreciate all the help.

```
def delete_char(string):
      string = list(string)
      string.remove("\n")
      return ''.join(string)

delete_char("I want \n to test \n if you \n work")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `replace`, instead?

```
def delete_char(string, target_char, replacement_char=""):
      return string.replace(target_char, replacement_char)

print(delete_char("I want \n to test \n if you \n work", "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-assign the string value to the removed form. Additionally I would suggest using replace instead of remove in this place, and replacing it with an empty character. Something like this should work:

```py
def delete_char(string):
      string = string.replace("\n", "")
      return string
```

Comment: I am kinda confused now.. I try to run the code you've posted, but nothing happens?

Comment: @Buni odd, that works for me in removing the newlines. It looks like Alex gave you a sufficient and similar answer anyway though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `str.split` and `str.join`:

```
>>> ' '.join("I want \n to test \n if you \n work".split())
I want to test if you work
```

This isn't the same as just removing the newline character but it will ensure only one space between words.

Otherwise just replace the newline with nothing:

```
>>> "I want \n to test \n if you \n work".replace('\n', '')
I want  to test  if you  work
```